# PrimeNg p-steps custom route

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to implement a fetaure something like if you have any unsaved changes, the page show some warning. I have p-steps implementation is place. Currently If I click on any steps, I will route to page which is binded for that steps.

Now what I need is, if there is any unsaved changes (unsaved changes I will take care of), and I click on any steps, so instead of routing to the page it is binded with, it show some warning like "**You have usaved changes. Do you want to save it!!!**" If user click on YES, it call some method/function to save the data and route to the page. If user click on NO, it directly route to it's page without calling any function.

Answer (score 0):

if not too hard to do what you are talking about, but I think you need to simplify things.

step 1) Have a boolean flag changesMadeFlg that defaults to false, but is set to true if changes are made.

step 2) If some presses a button to navigate away, check the flag. if false, let them navigate.

step 3) If changesMadeFlg is true, don't navigate anywhere, but instead show a confirmation popup. If they press "continue", then let them navigate away, otherwise stay on the page